# sub theme not inheriting css

Tags: 7, theming

I have a theme, and many subthemes, with the goal of creating a network of sites that are different, but share some resources (like the stackexchange sites do).
What I want is to include lots of boilerplate css in the master theme, and then site specific css included for each subtheme.
The problem I have is the CSS of the master theme is not being loaded in the subtheme.

The master theme:

```
name = Master
description = Master theme
core = 7.x

stylesheets[all][] = css/network_style.css
```

and the sub theme:

```
name = Red Theme
description = specific theme for site in network
core = 7.x

base theme = Master


stylesheets[all][] = css/red_style.css
```

Ideally then, the master theme just has network_style.css, and the sub theme has network_style.css and red_style.css.

If I enabled the master theme, then the network_style.css is applied. If I enabled the sub theme, then only the red_style.css is applied. There's no css conflict, and the master theme isn't visible in the page source at all.

Where am I going wrong? I'm somewhat new to Drupal.
I've gone through lots of documentation on the drupal site, and checked through all the drupal 7 specific stuff on theming.
I've tried clearing the drupal cache, plus my browsers cache, even turning server on and off like a mad man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base theme` should be set to the machine name of the Base Theme. The machine name is the same as the name of the directory that contains it. Yours starts with a capital letter. I imagine that the folder is just `master` (all lowercase).

Because the .info file is cached, you must clear the cache before any changes are displayed in your site.

[Writing theme `.info` files](https://www.drupal.org/node/171205)